# Discord.js unable to send message, did discord change something?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, message

This code has been working in the past, however I found out that `channel.send` is no longer working, any idea why or how I'm supposed to send messages?

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity("I'm online!", { type: 'PLAYING' });
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNELID')
    channel.send(`**Hello!**`);
  console.log('Bot is online!')
  })
});
```

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

I have no idea why it's not working anymore...

Comment: You are cycling through all the guilds...?

Comment: How I'm supposed to do that?

Comment: No you are doing it but you aren't supposed to... choose a guild with `let guild = client.guilds.cache.get("id")` and choose a channel with `guild.channels.cache.get("id")`

Comment: I found a way to make it work.. thank you anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is working... not sure why and would like to have explanation why the previous code was printing undefined error, however I don't know.

Solution:
`client.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').send('Hello!');`

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity("I'm online", { type: 'PLAYING' });
  client.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').send(`**Hello!**`);
  console.log('Bot is online!')
});
```

Comment: You received the `undefined` error because you were looping through all guilds trying to access a certain channel. If the channel is not found, it will throw `undefined` or `null` which means, there is no channel found. That's why your second code works and the first one throws TypeErrors. Why it worked previously, I have no idea, it shouldn't have is what I at least think.